# querySelectorAll not working in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

This is the gallery I am talking about that has issues with ie8: 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/21/google-grid-gallery/

This is the line where js breaks:

```
var x = this.grid.querySelectorAll( 'li:not(.grid-sizer)' );
```

But I think the problem starts much earlier. When I try to debug it using developer tools of ie8, there is no "this" in locals tab.

Comment: If the problem starts much earlier, we need to see the code from much earlier.

Comment: Besides duplicity, this question is off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart The link I posted has the entire code including demo and everything.

Comment: @user3692125 linking to code isn't sufficient to satisfy the requirement Guilherme mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 supports [`querySelectorAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc304115(v=vs.85).aspx), but not the [`:not` pseudo-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/jj127341.aspx). We did ship support for the latter in Internet Explorer 9, but if you would like to use it in IE 8 you would be better off using jQuery, where [it has been supported](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) since version 1.

With your desire to support IE 8, be sure to download and use a 1.x version of jQuery.